# rejected after 3 interviews

Tags: hiring-process, references, hiring, recommendation-letter, rejection

After three interviews and the 4th being planified I didn't get the job because of bad reference, that I gave earlier in the process. They contacted the manager who said he wouldn't recommend me for a job with those requirements.

What do you suggest? Should I confront the hiring manager and give another reference or should I just let it go? Or just send a post rejection thank you letter hoping they'll get back to me when a position is open?

Comment: Let it go, there's no point confronting anyone.  Complaining isn't going to change anything.  Move on.

Comment: Be professional and courteous. Send a thank you note to the interviewer and apologize for the unfortunate reference. If you are in the US, and if you think the manager who gave you the bad reference, did this without a merit, you might have a legal course of action.

Comment: No use of any confrontation and no use of  a thank you letter. Forget it , move on to the hunt for the  next opportunity.

Comment: (and do not use that person again as a reference)

Comment: From a constructive-criticism point of view it might be worth talking to the manager who gave you a bad reference to understand why he did, and why he couldn't recommend you for those job requirements. After all you're stuck working for him again for the time being so even if you never use him as a reference again you need to try and fix your working relationship.

Comment: @Rup The OP doesn't state the bad reference is from their current boss.

Comment: Always call your references before a potential employer calls them.  You need to know what they will say.

Comment: Point of order people: **this isn't necessarily a *bad* reference**. The OP's manager only said that he couldn't recommend the OP for this particular job. For all we know OP applied for a Software Architect position after working in customer support for 2 years, misrepresented his experience or otherwise applied for a job that he won't excel in. If that's the case it's normal for the reference to be unable to recommend him. Normally the OP would alert his reference about the job and the manager would then explain that he couldn't recommend him. My guess is that the OP didn't warn his reference

Comment: @Lilienthal That seems unlikely if they made it through three interviews. Or those interviews were not very rigorous.

Comment: @TheAnathema I'm deliberately providing extreme examples. People can intentionally or unintentionally misrepresent the kind of work they did and how much experience they have in certain areas. As a more realistic example a company might be filling a position for a web developer in technology X using framework Y. Someone who developed in X on a product that happened to use framework Y, but who never actually worked with Y, might reasonably think that he's qualified. While the interviewer should check that Y was a core part of the job, that doesn't always come out. [...]

Comment: But if the reference [asks what the nature of the job](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63139/) is he might be told that they're looking for someone to work on Y with some minor work on X. In that case the right course of action for the reference is to explain that while the candidate would be perfect for a role in X, he can't recommend the candidate if it mainly involves Y, because that wasn't part of the job he's basing the reference on. [This article](http://www.askamanager.org/2015/08/did-my-friend-give-me-a-damaging-reference.html) covers a somewhat similar situation.

Comment: you got stabbed in the back by someone you thought would back you up with a reference, learn from it. If anything I'd confront that manager, but not the place I applied to. Don't forget the person who did you a bad turn either.

Answer (score 8):

If the company got a bad reference they are not likely to change their mind so just write a thank you letter.

Hopefully you asked the person in advance if they would be a reference.  If a person cannot be a positive reference they would typically decline.  I would talk to the reference and ask why he could not recommend you for the job.  If you do not think you could get a positive reference from this person in the future then don't use them.

Comment: @JhonyDoe No reason for that language

Answer (score 1):

I believe it may be worth contacting the manager who provided a bad reference and asking for *why* they believe you were a bad fit for the position.

You may find that:

- They did not understand the job description and its requirements fully. If you truly believe you're a good fit, it's a possibility, and you can incorporate that somehow into your question. Sometimes this happens. I myself found the lines blurred between frontend/backend software development on a few different openings prior to looking into it more.
- They have some constructive criticism and explanations that will benefit you personally.
- It is possible (though this should be treated with the utmost care and due diligence) that the bad reference was a malicious act. You must absolutely be certain that this is the case. A bad reference rooted in maliciousness and falsehood is illegal. Understand, though, that opinions are protected, and are not necessarily malicious.

This is up to you, but moving forward in the future, you should not use them as a reference again. If I were you, I'd contact my references ahead of time in the future.

Definitely be courteous and polite, and send a thank you letter as you would normally.